# httplib python/wxpython. sock stream error

Tags: python, wxpython, httplib

I'm trying to check a few URLs to see if they come back as OK before I further manipulate them, I have a list of URLs in self.myList, which then runs these through the httplib HTTP Connection to get the response, however I get a load of errors from the httplib in cmd.

the code works, as I've tested with the below and it correctly comes back and sets the value in a wx.TextCtrl:

```
#for line in self.myList:
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
            conn.request("HEAD", "/")
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
            self.urlFld.SetValue(str(r1))
```

It just doesn't seem to work when I pass it more than 1 URL from myList.

```
for line in self.myList:
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(line)
            conn.request("HEAD", "/")
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
            self.urlFld.SetValue(line + "\t\t" + str(r1))
```

The errors I get on cmd are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gui_texteditor_men.py", line 96, in checkBtnClick
conn.request("HEAD", "/")
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 958, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

**Edit**, updated code using urlparse. I have imported urlparse.

```
for line in self.myList:
            url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
            conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
            self.urlFld.AppendText(url.hostname + "\t\t" + str(r1))
```

with traceback,

```
C:\Python27\Coding>python gui_texteditor_men.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gui_texteditor_men.py", line 97, in checkBtnClick
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 693, in __init__
self._set_hostport(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 712, in _set_hostport
i = host.rfind(':')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

I now have www.google.com and www.bing.com in a .txt file, when it throws this error.

**Edit 2**
@ Aya,

looks like it failed due to the "\n" between the 2 URLs. I thought I coded it to remove the "\n" with .strip() but seems it didnt have any effect.

```
Failed on u'http://www.google.com\nhttp://www.bing.com'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gui_texteditor_men.py", line 99, in checkBtnClick
conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 958, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I took another look at my .strip() when I open the file,

```
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        directory, filename = dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()
        self.filePath = '/'.join((directory, filename))
        self.fileTxt.SetValue(self.filePath)
        self.urlFld.LoadFile(self.filePath)
        self.myList = self.urlFld.GetValue().strip()
```

and now it traceback errors with  "Failed on u'h'"

Thanks

Comment: Which errors do you geT?

Comment: Sounds like one of the URLs contains an invalid hostname.

Comment: it does, its like www.blahlsghsh.com  but surely that should go and attempt it then come back as 404 not found?   EDIT: jsut took out the fake hostname and tried again, same errors with just google.com and bing.com so its not that affecting it

Comment: You'll only get a 404 if the hostname is valid, but the path isn't. If the hostname doesn't exist, you'll get a DNS lookup fail.

Comment: changed it to a valid hostname and "myfakepage.html" so should return 404, still get all errors.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error this time? I'm almost certain it won't be `getaddrinfo failed`, but something else. Edit: never mind - I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.myList` contains a list of URLs, you can't use them directly in the `HTTPConnection` constructor like you do here...

```
for line in self.myList:
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(line)
    conn.request("HEAD", "/")
```

The `HTTPConnection` constructor should only be passed the hostname part of the URL, and the request method should be given the path part. You'll need to parse the URL with something like...

```
import urlparse

for line in self.myList:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
    conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
```

**Update**

Can you change the code to...

```
for line in self.myList:
    try:
        url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
        conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
        r1 = conn.getresponse()
        r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
        self.urlFld.AppendText(url.hostname + "\t\t" + str(r1))
    except:
        print 'Failed on %r' % line
        raise
```

...and include the full output of running it?

**Update #2**

I'm not quite sure what `self.fileTxt` and `self.urlFld` are supposed to do, but if you're just reading lines from `self.filePath`, you only need...

```
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    directory, filename = dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()
    self.filePath = '/'.join((directory, filename))
    self.myList = [line.strip() for line in open(self.filePath, 'r').readlines()]
```

Comment: ok thanks. didn't know i couldnt pass urls to httplib. i tried as you suggested,
`for line in self.myList:
                url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
                conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
                conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
                r1 = conn.getresponse()
                r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
                self.urlFld.AppendText(url.hostname + "\t\t" + str(r1))`

and get a cmd error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

Comment: @directpixel can you update the original question and append the new code and the new traceback in full, please?

Comment: @directpixel which URL is it failing on this time?

Comment: fails on www.google.com and www.bing.com in a .txt file which makes up myList

Comment: @directpixel Well, those aren't valid URLs - change them to `http://www.google.com` and `http://www.bing.com` respectively.

Comment: i tried that before i wrote you a comment as i thought you may mention that :). the traceback error i get then is the same as it was at the very beginning.
    `for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`   etc

Comment: @directpixel The bug will be in the code which creates `self.myList`, so you'll have to include that.

Comment: updated the original post to include the creation of self.myList

Comment: those are other bits, should have deleted them to avoid confusion. and that works brilliantly now, thanks a lot for the consistent help; really helped a lot